# OpenGL ES Interleaved Vertex Array with texture id

Tags: c++, opengl-es

Let's say we bind a simple array buffer in OpenGL ES:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_dataVboID);
```

We then tell the array buffer how our interleaved data is structured:

```
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, VBO_SIZE_MULTIPLIER, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, VBO_SIZE_MULTIPLIER, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(GLfloat) * 2));
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, VBO_SIZE_MULTIPLIER, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(GLfloat) * 2 + sizeof(GLubyte) * 4));
```

So we have:
float x, float y
ubyte r, ubyte g, ubyte b, ubyte a
float tx, float ty

Is it possible to have one more variable at the end with a texture id? I was thinking of using `glVertexAttribPointer` and use `texture2D` inside a fragment shader with the passed value.

Would that work?

The idea here is that I can use a single glDrawArrays instead of binding each texture id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can only bind a certain number of textures at once, and can't switch them in a shader*.

You can, however, use [array textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture), which are basically... an array of textures. This requires each texture to be the same size, and for you to store each texture into the array ahead of time.

<sup>* The [NV_bindless_texture](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/bindless_texture.txt) extension may allow it, but it's not widely supported yet.</sup>

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looping for.